# Forcing IE to embed @Font Face?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, font-face, embedding

I am working on a site with Font Face but my client's IE 11 and 12 are not loading them. After testing endlessly on many machines, and always having success, I am convinced that their IE are defaulted to not allow embedding. Is there a way around this?

Here is my CSSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'hirukoregular';
    src: url('fonts/thinkdust_-_hiruko-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/thinkdust_-_hiruko-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/thinkdust_-_hiruko-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/thinkdust_-_hiruko-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/thinkdust_-_hiruko-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/thinkdust_-_hiruko-webfont.svg#hirukoregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Comment: Use a webfont rather than one locally? I find it odd that IE would actually prevent usage of **locally served** fonts.

Comment: I need to use a particular brand font. Once font embedding is turned on through IE it works fine, but I am hoping there's a way for it work when it's turned on?